# Trying to match a string and add it to the replacement

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to add a string to the end of a line using sed and regex.

I have the following string:

```
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
```

and im trying to add to the end of it the string:

```
exec,system,shell_exec,passthru,
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
sed -ie 's/disable_functions = .*[a-zA-z,]$/disable_functions = $1exec,system,shell_exec,passthru,/gI' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

It seems to just add $1 to the string disable_functions = $1exec,system,shell_exec,passthru,

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that :

```
sed '/^disable_functions/s/$/exec,system,shell_exec,passthru,/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

If the output seems OK, then add `-i` switch to modify the file.

`$` here, mean *end of line*.

Answer (score 1):

Your original command is missing the capture group which sets the value of `\1` (not `$1`):

```
sed -ie 's/disable_functions = \(.*[a-zA-z,])\$/disable_functions = \1exec,system,shell_exec,passthru,/gI' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

But as `sputnick` points out, you simply need to find the appropriate line and append the desired text; there's no need to match the old values and reinsert them.